# What does "fully depleted" mean?

Tags: solid-state-physics, dark-matter, particle-detectors

In many papers/articles on CCDs, particularly those used for dark energy surveys and dark matter detection, the term "fully depleted CCD" is used. What does this mean?

References:

1. http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6185
2. http://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C0604032/talks/snic_holland.pdf